# WPF: Binding Hierarchy

Tags: wpf, data-binding, hierarchy

I have defined a default binding in my style.

For example I have configured the visibility binding of my button so that it must not be visible if the relative command can not execute.

This is my **default binding behavior**.

Apart from my default behavior, every view can customize the buttons it uses with *another visibility binding*.

**I want to combine the two bindings so that if any of two say "it's not visible" it will be not visible!**

In other words, is it possibile to create a *binding behavior hierarchy*? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, not possible in XAML.

You CAN do this combination in code, though. You can write a BindingConverter for this.

Answer (score 3):

use a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx.) to wire up all the different bindings in XAML, and write your own [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) that prioritises / ands / ors each value as you like. You can't use a MultiBinding without an IMultiValueConverter (or a StringFormat, but that's no use to you)

Note that PriorityBinding is NOT what you are looking for here.

here's a valueConverter you can use:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(Visibility))]
public class BooleansAndToVisibilityMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Func<bool, bool, bool> aggregator = (x, y) => x && y;
        bool aggregate = values.Cast<bool>().Aggregate(aggregator);
        return aggregate ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's a good solution but I have two bindings collapsing in the same property: a "visibility" setted in theme and a "visibility" setted in xaml